# Python `for` syntax: block code vs single line generator expressions

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm familiar with the `for` loop in a block-code context. eg:

```
for c in "word":
    print c
```

I just came across some examples that use `for` differently. Rather than beginning with the `for` statement, they tag it at the end of an expression (and don't involve an indented code-block). eg:

```
sum(x*x for x in range(10))
```

Can anyone point me to some documentation that outlines this use of `for`? I've been able to find examples, but not explanations. All the `for` documentation I've been able to find describes the previous use (block-code example). I'm not even sure what to call this use, so I apologize if my question's title is unclear.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What you are pointing to is `Generator` in Python. Take a look at: -

- http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators
- http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/
- http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-342-new-generator-features

See the documentation: - [`Generator Expression`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) which contains exactly the same example you have posted

From the documentation: -

> Generators are a simple and powerful tool for creating iterators. They
>   are written like regular functions but use the yield statement
>   whenever they want to return data. Each time next() is called, the
>   generator resumes where it left-off (it remembers all the data values
>   and which statement was last executed)

Generators are similar to `List Comprehension` that you use with `square brackets` instead of `brackets`, but they are more memory efficient. They don't return the complete `list` of result at the same time, but they return generator object. Whenever you invoke `next()` on the `generator` object, the generator uses `yield` to return the next value.

`List Comprehension` for the above code would look like: -

```
[x * x for x in range(10)]
```

You can also add conditions to filter out results at the end of the for.

```
[x * x for x in range(10) if x % 2 != 0]
```

This will return a list of `numbers` multiplied by 2 in the range 1 to 5, if the number is not divisible by 2.

An example of `Generators` depicting the use of `yield` can be: -

```
def city_generator():
    yield("Konstanz")
    yield("Zurich")
    yield("Schaffhausen")
    yield("Stuttgart")

>>> x = city_generator()
>>> x.next()
Konstanz
>>> x.next()
Zurich
>>> x.next()
Schaffhausen
>>> x.next()
Stuttgart
>>> x.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

So, you see that, every call to `next()` executes the next `yield()` in `generator`. and at the end it throws `StopIteration`.

Comment: generators and also list comprehensions, which look very similar: `[x*x for x in range(10)]`. You can also include a condition to filter results out: `[x*x for x in range(10) if x % 2 == 0 or x % 3 == 0]`.

Answer (score 9):

Those are [generator expressions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) and they are related to [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

List comprehensions allow for the easy creation of lists. For example, if you wanted to create a list of perfect squares you could do this:

```
>>> squares = []
>>> for x in range(10):
...     squares.append(x**2)
...
>>> squares
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

But instead you could use a list comprehension:

```
squares = [x**2 for x in range(10)]
```

Generator expressions are like list comprehensions, except they return a generator object instead of a list. You can iterate over this generator object in a similar manner to list comprehensions, but you don't have to store the whole list in memory at once, as you would if you created the list in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Your specific example is called a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions). [List comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/), [dictionary comprehensions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), and [set comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) are similar in meaning (different result types, and generator expressions are lazy) and have the same syntax, modulo being inside other kinds of brackets, and in the case of a dict comprehension having `expr1: expr2` instead of a single expression (x*x in your example).

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for generator expressions is here https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/
Following is the code using generator expression .

```
list(x**2 for x in range(0,10))
```