# For Loop questions

Tags: python

I'm used to seeing `For` Loops in this format:

`for number in l:
        sum = sum + number`

I was browsing some forums and came across this piece of code:

```
count_chars = ".arPZ"
string = "Phillip S. is doing a really good job."
counts = tuple(string.count(d) for(d)  in count_chars)

print counts
```

I'm not sure if that is really a  `For` loop, so I decided to rewrite it in a way that I understood:

```
tuple(
for(d) in count_chars:
    string.count(d))
```

Needless to say, it failed lol. So can someone explain what is going on, and explain the folly of my logic? Thanks!!

Comment: This is called a generator expression. I am sure someone will post a more expert answer than I will write.

Comment: Thanks for getting me in the right direction. I had no idea what a generator expression was!

Comment: [Here is a short video about list comprehensions and it's siblings, including generator expressions.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw)

Comment: @user3386440 Nobody posted anything (correct) so I wrote something up, see below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python \`for\` syntax: block code vs single line generator expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920214/python-for-syntax-block-code-vs-single-line-generator-expressions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not quite a `for` loop as such, but a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions). What it basically does is return an iterator where each element is the amount of time every character in `count_chars` occurs in `d`. It then adds all of these elements into a `tuple`.

It is (roughly) equivalent to:

```
counts = []
for d in count_chars:
    counts.append(string.count(d))
counts = tuple(counts)
```

Comment: @user3386440 declare an empty list `counts`. For every element in `count_chars`, count how many times it is in `string` and add that number to the list `counts`. Convert `counts` to a tuple.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll look up `append` on my own but I think I got the rest of it. Assume I didn't want it to appear on a list ie: `(2,2,1,1,0)`. Instead I want it to be be simply print out. I will show you want I mean in the OP.