# Towards understanding One Line For loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, apache-spark, pyspark

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920214/python-for-syntax-block-code-vs-single-line-generator-expressions) question, I have this PySpark code:

```
model = KMeansModel(model.Cs[0])
first_split = split_vecs.map(lambda x: x[0])
model.computeCost(first_split)
model = KMeansModel(model.Cs[1])
second_split = split_vecs.map(lambda x: x[1])
model.computeCost(second_split)
```

Can I write this into a one-liner for loop? Or these loops are restricted in having *only one* line in their body?

Note: I am not looking for code-only answers, I want to learn, so please, explain. :)

---

Here is my tragic attempt:

```
model.computeCost(split) for i in range(2): # <- the semicolon here doesn't feel right..Where to put the other lines?
```

---

Edit:

Yes, I know that I can write a regular [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop), but I would like to understand one-liner for loops. This is for experimenting. You see, when reading others' people code, I see them often, and I am not comfortable with them... :/

Comment: What advantage will your one-liner offer over a regular for-loop? Or you want a comprehension?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye check my update. It's mostly for understanding them, so that when I meet them in others' people code I will be comfortable. I do not have the experience to answer your second question, improvise! :)

Comment: I think by "one-line for loop" you are taking about list comprehensions.

Comment: Hmm it could be @DanielRoseman, which means that the answer to my question is No, right? You see, I don't really know [tag:Python] that's why I am trying to learn..And ask bad question(s), I guess :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list comprehension version of what you did in that example would be:

```
[KMeansModel(model.Cs[i]).computeCost(split_vecs.map(lambda x: x[i])) for i in range(2)]
```

This is no different than:

```
results = []
for i in range(2):
    results.append(KMeansModel(model.Cs[i]).computeCost(split_vecs.map(lambda x: x[i])))
```

So for each `i`, it appends the returning value of that chained expression to the list. For this example, it happened to work because your three lines could be chained together. You are calling `computeCost()` method on the object you created with `KMeansModel(model.Cs[0])` and the parameter for that is `split_vecs.map(lambda x: x[0])`.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the three distinct functions you have (KMeansModel,split_vec.map, and computeCost) in another function, like so:

```
def master_fx(var):
    return fx_C(fx_B(fx_A(var)))
```

Now that it looks nice, you can either use list comprehension:

```
[master_fx(element) for element in range(2)]
```

Or a for loop (on one or more lines -- it generally makes no difference, except in terms of readability. I say generally because I do get an error when I try to put another control structure on the same line, as in:

```
for i in range(2): if i%2==0: print(i)
```

However, for readability's sake, you probably wouldn't want something like the line above anyway)

Probably the most important difference is that a for loop is just a control structure whereas list comprehension is a fancy kind of list over which you can define operations. That is why in an interactive interpreter such as ipython, you have to print the output (element and i in the examples above) of a for loop but not of list comprehension.

Comment: Cool, thanks!!! It surprises me that I have 3.5 answers, in a question of 0 score. :P

Answer (score 2):

What you're calling "one-liner for loops" are actually called"list comprehensions", "dictionary comprehensions", or "[generator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators) expressions". They are more limited than for-loops, and work as follows:

```
# List comprehension
result = [expression for name in iterable]
# equivalent to:
result = []
for name in iterable:
    result.append(expression)

# Dictionary comprehension
result = {key_expression: value_expression for name in iterable}
# equivalent to:
result = {}
for name in iterable:
    result[key_expression] = value_expression

# Generator expression
result = (expression for name in iterable)
# equivalent to
def anonymous_generator():
    for name in iterable:
        yield expression
result = anonymous_generator()
```

You can nest them, they aren't actually required to be one line. For a (probably-not-useful) example, list comprehensions could be used to get a list of all possible pairs of elements from a list `listA` and elements from lists in a dict `dictB` keyed by things from `listA` (the line break is not required, but helps readability):

```
pairs = [(a, b) for a in listA
                for b in dictB[a]]
# equivalent to:
pairs = []
for a in listA:
    for b in dictB[a]:
        pairs.append(a, b)
```

However, the main limitation of them is that you can't call arbitrary functions - the only places you can put expressions are when saying what iterables you're using and what to output into the result. Side-effects of any functions you call in that will happen, though! For your specific case, you can't do it in any of those simply, because you keep re-assigning model and you can't do that in the middle of a comprehension. It's probably possible to twist things around enough to get the same effect (by writing other functions that do the assignment as a side-effect before returning the correct value), but in this case not really worth it.

Comment: Thank you very much of your explanation David! Such a lovely feeling to see a good answer like this, even though my question is 0 scored!

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but it looks like it could work for you

```
computedCost = [KMeansModel(model.Cs[i]).computeCost(x[i]) for i in xrange(2)]
```

What it does is create a list of results after performing computeCost() on the results of `KMeansModel()`.  the `xrange for loop` just returns the values for i

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the semi colon. Though honestly I wouldn't recommend using one line for statements outside of generator expressions

Comment: But where should the other lines would go? Did you read my whole comment? Well, I don't really know Python, so I am trying to understand what is the principal behind this..

Comment: @gsamaras just do regular for loop?

Comment: That won't actually help, as OP using `split` as the argument to the `computeCost` function, while the for loop sets `i`.

Comment: Yes I know how to to a regular for loop. I am asking about the one-liner version, since I am trying to understand one-liner for loops.

Comment: Ohhhhh, typically one line loops are used to generate lists or iterables in place like in a lambda or something.

Comment: If by one-liner loops you mean list comprehensions, you cannot do assignment in them.

Comment: @ayhan is that the answer to this `Can I write this into a one-liner for loop? Or these loops are restricted in having only one line in their body?`? Because if it is, it should be posted as an answer (with an explanation please).

Comment: @gsamaras For this specific question, I honestly don't know because I don't know the returning values. But it's not a matter of lines. You can always do something like `[KMeansModel(model.Cs[i]).computeCost(split_vecs.map(lambda x: x[i])) for i in range(2)]` but would it work for that library? I don't know.

Comment: It worked @ayhan, that's it! Can you please post an answer and explain that piece of code a little bit? :) Why we needed a list for example, would worth an explanation. Without it I will get a syntax error.