# Python multiple files loop

Tags: python

I just created a loop to read through each line in multiple files in Python and my code looks like this:

```
filenames = ["a.txt","b.txt","c.txt","d.txt"]
for file in filenames:  
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(file)]
```

However, Python only returns the contents of the last file (d.txt).

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `lines` is being overwrite on each iteration with the content of the actual file. Rakesh solution is valid, but I'm giving you other approach, as you are trying to do it in 1 line:

```
filenames = ["a.txt","b.txt","c.txt", "d.txt"]
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for file in filenames for line in open(file)]
```

Comment: I have another loop in this read file loop to, your code does not allow me to use other loop.     lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for file in filenames for line in open(file)] 
  for r in range(11):
  for c in range(5):

Comment: You have to put that for loops inside the `[...]` section. You can't place them outside. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920214/python-for-syntax-block-code-vs-single-line-generator-expressions) you have a more detailed explanation about 1 line generator.

Your version for this loop would be something like this:
`[print(r,c,file, line) for r in range(11) for c in range(5) for file in filenames for line in open(file)]`

Comment: [Here in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) you have even more info about it works